# deleting helm deployments automatically

Tags: scripting, kubernetes

I have requirement where I want to delete all pods deployed through helm after a certain amount of time.
This process needs to be automated. This is a detail of 3 existing deployed helm instances:

```
ubuntu@kops:~$ helm ls
NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   NAMESPACE
dandy-vulture           1               Mon May 14 07:21:17 2018        DEPLOYED        mak15-0.1.0             default
dapper-pig              1               Sun May 13 16:32:58 2018        DEPLOYED        naseer-0.1.0            default
eerie-dragonfly         1               Mon May 14 07:13:15 2018        DEPLOYED        mak12-0.1.0             default
```

I want to delete all deployments which are at least four hours old.
The manual process of deleting a helm deployment, shown below, should be automated.

```
# helm delete dandy-vulture
```

Comment: I haven't worked with `helm` directly, so I attempted an answer based on the helm source code and your sample output. I noticed that your sample "helm delete" command showed a deletion of the *newest* instance, based on the `UPDATED` field. I would have expected `dapper-pig` to be the (semi-arbitrary) instance to delete.

Comment: I just added an arbitrary requirement to my solution that the "STATUS" be "DEPLOYED". Update the question if that's a bad assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a system with GNU date (such as a Linux system), you could use awk to parse the output of `helm ls`, then use GNU date to compute the seconds-since-the-epoch and determine if the corresponding deployment is old enough:

```
helm ls | awk -v now=$(date +%s) -f delete-old-deployments.awk
```

Where the contents of `delete-old-deployments.awk` are:

```
BEGIN {
  # age cutoff, in seconds
  cutoff=4 * 60 * 60
}

NR > 1 {
        split($0, elements, /   */)
        "date -d '" elements[3] "' +%s" | getline elesecs
        if ((now - elesecs) > cutoff && elements[4] == "DEPLOYED") {
            system("helm delete '"elements[1]"'")

        }
}
```

Based on what I can gather from the [helm ls source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/list.go), the output is a whitespace-separated table of various strings. As such, I've asked awk to split each line (after skipping the header) based on 2 or more spaces (there are three spaces in the third parameter to the split() function; two, followed by zero-or-more spaces).

The third such field after splitting is the date string, which we pass to GNU date, asking it to convert that to seconds-since-the-epoch. If the difference between "now" and "then" is more than the cutoff, then we call the `helm delete` command on the corresponding name.